# How to draw the reverse automaton for this language to show that L is regular.

Tags: computer-science, formal-languages, automata, regular-language

**The problem :**

Let $\sum$ be the alphabets of 8 symbols :
[image]

A word  $w \in \Sigma^*$ of length $n$ can be seen as a suite of $n$ columns of 3 bits or $3$ rows of $n$ bits.

These rows can be seen as 3 whole numbers a,b,c in binary.

Show that language $L \subseteq \Sigma^*$ of $w$ such as a + b = c is a regular language.

Example:
[image] because a = 2, b= 3 and c = 5 (2 + 3 = 5)

**My problem :**

There's a theorem  that if we show that $L^r$ is regular then $L$ is regular.

So i have to draw the reverse automaton of this but i am not sure how to do. There must be a pattern to recognize to draw this easily but i don't see it.

It's been proposed that we read the less significative number first. (the first column on the right)

Also it will be easier to draw the automaton if you replace each symbols by 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7 ( no need to draw all the columns on the automaton).

Anyone could give me an idea on how to draw this. Would be greatly appreciated. Also, here's a drawing tool if u wanna help out. http://madebyevan.com/fsm/ Thank you.

**Edit for answer below**

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We need to remember if there was carry bit, and if word we read so far is correct. So, 3 states will be enough: valid without carry bit ($a$), valid with carry bit ($b$), invalid ($c$). Initial state is $a$, accepting state is also $a$.

If we read $n$ bits so far, giving number $x$ in the first row, $y$ in the second and $z$ in the third, automaton will be in state $a$ iff $x + y = z$, in state $b$ iff $x + y = 2^n + z$, and in $c$ otherwise.

Transitions are pretty straightforward:

- anything from $c$ goes to $c$
- $000$ transitions $a$ to $a$, and $b$ to $c$
- $001$ transitions $a$ to $c$ and $b$ to $a$
- $010$ transitions $a$ to $c$ and $b$ to $b$
- $110$ transitions $a$ to $b$ and $b$ to $c$
- $111$ transitions $a$ to $c$ and $b$ to $b$

and so on.

In general, if we read $uvw$ and assume $p = 0$ if state was $a$ and $p = 1$ if it was $b$, we need to check $w = u \oplus v \oplus p$ (if not - move to $c$), and move to $a$ if $u + v + p < 2$ and to $b$ otherwise.

Comment: @mihalid Thank for reply, could you go a little bit more in details, i think i am more visual. I am not quite sure i understand the reasoning behind the transitions given, you seem to have a pattern but i don't understand it, like from the last transition you give, i wouldn't know what to do next.  ( haven't figured the pattern) i edited the post with a diagram with the transitions u mentionned. Thank you.

Comment: @mihalid also i am not too sure what you mean with valid without carry bit , valid with carry bit and invalid.

Comment: Added some description what states mean, is it enough for you to finish the pattern?

Comment: @mihalid I am a bit confused, let's say i take one of your transitions : 001 you say it goes from a to c and b to a but why ? Could you give  an exemple with numbers in your equations i don't really get it haha. Also won't this give the normal automaton and not the reverse ? Thanks.

Comment: @codetime: mihalid is just doing (binary) addition in the normal way, right to left, the way you would do it on paper (assuming that people still use pencil and paper to do addition). The states could be named better, but they're well described. $c$ means the addition is wrong. $b$ means that the addition up to this point (right-to-left, remember) is fine, and produces a carry for the next position. $a$ means the addition up to this point is fine and does not produce a carry. If you're in state $a$ and you see $0 0 1$, then that's wrong. But if you're in $b$ (with carry) then it's fine.

Comment: @rici Honestly, maybe it's trying to read the graph that i don't understand, like if i read a 001 at a, i have no clue why it takes you to C, is x=0 , y=0 , z=1 ? Cause there i could see the 0 + 0 != z. But it must not be that because if you read  a 001 at b u go to a. Also when do you go to b ?  I just don't get the equation i understand where the n is coming from, but when i read the graph i am not sure which n to take. Thank you.

Comment: If you read $001$ in state $b$, you know, there was carry bit. For example, $110$ moves us from $a$ to $b$, then $001$ moves us from $b$ to $a$. And this is accept state: in this case $x = y = 01$, $z = 10$, so $x + y = z$.

Comment: @mihaild I edited a new graph in the question, if i understand right this would be the reverse graph for the question right ? Correct me if i am wrong, thanks again.

Comment: $3$ and $5$ should move $a$ to $a$. Yes, automaton for original language is reversed graph for the reversed language. Note that reversed automaton is non-deterministic, so if you need a deterministic automaton you will have to determinize it.

Comment: @mihaild Oops you're right i edited my graph. Thanks for your help and patience.